# How to repeat or re- select the selected segment on HMSegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, scroll, uisegmentedcontrol

In HMSegmentedControl, I want to perform repeated segment selection. Means If a segment is selected already,  If it's press or select again it should perform/ reload the next functions on the basis of segment selection.

Comment: are you using pod or just classes ? swift or objc?

Comment: @JayeshThanki I'm using Just classes and It's in Objective C. Thanks

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `HMSegmentedControl.swift` file, there is `tapped(segmentButton:)` function in which you can just change `indexChanged` bool variable to true or you can remove `indexChanged` variable from if condition then every time you tap selected tab event will occures. Here is actual function code :

## Swift

```
func tapped(segmentButton sender: UIButton) {
    let newIndex = sender.tag
    //let indexChanged: Bool = newIndex != selectedSegmentIndex
    let indexChanged: Bool = true
    selectedSegmentIndex = newIndex

    if let indexChangedHandler = indexChangedHandler, indexChanged == true {
        indexChangedHandler(selectedSegmentIndex)
    }

    setSelectedSegmentIndex(newIndex, animated: true)
}
```

**OR**

```
func tapped(segmentButton sender: UIButton) {
    let newIndex = sender.tag
    selectedSegmentIndex = newIndex

    if let indexChangedHandler = indexChangedHandler {
        indexChangedHandler(selectedSegmentIndex)
    }

    setSelectedSegmentIndex(newIndex, animated: true)
}
```

## Objective-C

you can remove `segment != self.selectedSegmentIndex` condition in this method `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

```
//if (segment != self.selectedSegmentIndex && segment < sectionsCount) {
if (segment < sectionsCount) {
    // Check if we have to do anything with the touch event
    if (self.isTouchEnabled)
        [self setSelectedSegmentIndex:segment animated:self.shouldAnimateUserSelection notify:YES];
}
```

NOTE : commented line (1st line) is old code and 2nd line is new code.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help  :)